# How can we call a function in a .js from a .html file

Tags: javascript, html

In my `index.html` file I have:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

`myFunction` is located in `index.js`

how can I call this function when the button is clicked?

Comment: include js file in <script> tag and it will get called

Comment: Kind of a novince question, I would recommend you taking a look at w3school website for the basic knowledge about html/css/js

Answer (score 1):

Add the `js` file `reference` in your `html page` so its functions can be called from `html` page.

```
<script src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

Also give your button `type="button"` otherwise this `button` will `submit` the page and your `function` will not be called.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the index.js file at the bottom of your HTML, right before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="path/to/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to header:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're new to this all, so I'm going to try and explain it a little bit more than the answers above.

When you got your HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is the title of my page</title>
        <script src='js/script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you see this. The `<script>` tag says to the browser: "Okay, there is coming up some javascript (or jQuery)" so it will look in the `src` attribute, to see where the javascript is found that should be loaded. When it finds it, it will load it into the html document and you will have the functions in the file ready to be used in your html document. The `type` attribute just says: "Okay, this script is filled with javascript". You also have `type='text/css'` for example when you're including a CSS script to style the HTML elements of the page.

Hope it makes sence, and I wish you luck, learning html/css/javascript. If you have any questions, reply to this answer.